# Failed to install the app in react-native

Tags: android, react-native

**Android**

My application was running perfectly before and after some changes in some js files this error appeared

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 0s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Unable to install C:\projects\Maheema\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Gradlew clean
```

In android directory of your project
And then run on device again
.